# Is there a way to turn off ssl validation in citrus framework?

Tags: java, ssl, citrus-framework

I want to test a https (api) client.

But I want to turn off the `ssl validation` in citrus. Could you please let me know how to turn off the ssl validation?

```
(httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder 
.client("https://localhost") .send() .get() .header(....)
```

this is automatically checking for `ssl` certificate.

I am getting the following exception :

> PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException.

Is there any way to turn off ssl validation (just like we disable the `ssl` validation in postman or anyother framework ).

how will i add the context to the ssl context to the citrus test

http(httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder 
.client("https://....com") .send() .get() .header(....)

Comment: Post your code you have written so far, also post the exception details if you are getting.

Comment: (httpActionBuilder -> httpActionBuilder
                .client("https://localhost")
                .send()
                .get()
                .header(....)   this is automatically checking for ssl certificate - am getting the following exception :  PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following class

```
class NonValidatingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

And then in Spring `@Configuration` override default SSLContext by declaring new bean

```
@Bean
public SSLContext sslContext() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); // or try "SSL"
    ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new NonValidatingTrustManager() }, null);
    return ctx;
}
```

**UPDATE**

For tests you create separate config class and put there overridden SSLContext too:

```
@TestConfiguration
class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); // or try "SSL"
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new NonValidatingTrustManager() }, null);
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

And use it in unit test like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class })
class MyTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolay - I have added this code to my test.But could you please help me to understand how to pass the ssl context to citrus tests .thanks

Comment: I was thinking if there is any other method in citrus to do - like in rest assured we use relaxedhttpsvalidation()

Comment: @TestEngineer added example

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. I am trying to allow all the trusted certificates so that you can make https call.

```
try {
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }

        } };

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);     
HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build();               
}
catch (IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException e) {
        throw new BeanCreationException("Failed to create http client for ssl connection", e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sambit -How do i pass this ssl context to the citrus tests